# In Perl, using 'Spreadsheet::WriteExcel' for formatting but its not able to format the excel after 43 rows

Tags: perl

Below is the code, I'm using a while loop to write rows but getting only 43 formatted rows. How to solve this?

```
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $xls=@ARGV[0];
# Create a new workbook called simple.xls and add a worksheet
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($xls);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# The general syntax is write($row, $column, $token). Note that row and
# column are zero indexed

# Write some text
my $row=1;
$worksheet->write(0, 0,  'Hi Excel!');
while($row<100)
{
  my $format = $workbook->add_format();
  $format->set_bg_color('grey');
  $format->set_align('center');
  $worksheet->write($row, 1, "vikas veer",$format);
  $row++;
}
$workbook->close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [faq] about new posts and [edit] your question. It's not clear what you are asking right now.

Comment: When I run your code, I get 99 formatted rows. What's the problem?

Comment: m only getting 43 formatted rows...@choroba

Comment: Please stop writing `M` or `m`, write `am` or `I am` or `I'm`.

Comment: yeah sure @serenesat..i am so sorry abt. that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly. I have just modified your code. This will give you 100 formatted rows:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $xls = $ARGV[0];

# Create a new workbook called simple.xls and add a worksheet
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($xls);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Add and define a format
my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_bg_color('grey');
$format->set_align('center');

my $col = my $row = 0;
while($row<100)
{
    $worksheet->write($row, $col, "vikas veer", $format);
    $row++;
}
$workbook->close();
```

Comment: thank u @serenesat it's working properly now i m getting 100 formatted rows, i dont know what was wrong with previous code..

Comment: Even for me your previous code was giving 100 formatted rows. :)